# I'm looking for a superpower young adult novel that has a teen Asian boy's face in the cover

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, powers

I spotted this while browsing online. I can only remember a little of the summary. It's about a possessed teen with superpowers. The cover is of a teenaged Asian boy's face, his cheek is covered, it has something written on it.

Comment: Was the cover picture realistic looking, or more like a cartoon e.g. like a [light novel](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+light+novels&tbm=isch)?

Comment: No it a novel and the cover is photograph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it. The book is [Caster](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/43319656) by Elsie Chapman.

This is the cover picture I remembered:

[image]